# How to arrange a div in a grid?

Tags: html, css

I write cms and I want to display news on a page. On top is title and under news. I tryed display it only 2 columns w a row. I don't know where I make error. I hope someone help me.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#all  {
    background-color:silver;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
    row-gap:10px;
    
    
    
     
}

#all p{
    
    border:3px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:10px;

}
```

```html
<div id="all">
 <div class="tog">
    <h1 class="flex">
    <?php echo "<div class='flex'>" .$pokaz['tytul']. "</div>"; ?>
    </h1>
     <h2 class="tresc"> 
        <?php echo "<div class='tresc'>" .$pokaz['news']. "</div>"; ?>
    </h2>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tog {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  
  /* the rest is just to help visualize where the grid boundaries are. none of this is necessary. */
  gap: 24px;
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tog > * {
  /* just to help visualize where the grid boundaries are. not necessary for the layout. */
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="tog">
  <div>tytul</div>
  <div>news</div>
</div>
```

Your selector `#all` that defines the grid only has one child, `<div class="tog">`, so it's going to fill the first column. Move the grid setup to `.tog`.

Comment: Could you improve me code. I really don't have idea how change it.